# How do I Instantiate a variable number of objects? (C#)

Tags: c#, class, object

I'm currently making a program that needs to do read input from a file (using File.ReadAllLines() ), and I want to create an object for each of those lines. The problem I have is that (number of lines in) the file can obviously change often, so the number of objects I need to instantiate is not known by the compiler.

So for example:

```
string str[] = File.ReadAllLines();
int n = str.Length;
```

At this point I want to instantiate **n** objects of a class, how should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your class has a constructor to create itself from a string:

```
var myObjects = str.Select(x => new MyClass(x));
```

Note that this will not enumerate until you need these objects. If you want to force enumeration you could do:

```
var myObjects = str.Select(x => new MyClass(x)).ToList();
```

Example constructor:

```
public MyClass(string line)
{
    //parse the line and set variables of MyClass
}
```

Comment: Just do not forget to warn about the [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

Comment: @puko `str` is _array_, so `x` is _string_

Comment: he named his `string[]` `str`